# If $A$ is a positive operator, and if $AB$ is self-adjoint, then $\vert(ABx, x)\vert \leq \Vert B \Vert \cdot (Ax, x)$ in finite dimensional spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

Exercise 7(a) after $\S.$ 90 *Minimax principle* from Paul R. Halmos's "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces" (second edition) asks to prove or disprove the following assertion.

> If $A$ is a positive linear transformation on a finite-dimensional inner product space, and if $AB$ is self-adjoint, then $$\vert(ABx, x)\vert \leq \Vert B \Vert \cdot (Ax, x)$$ for all vectors $x$.

The underlying field is not specified as real or complex. Also, for reference, $\S . 87$ and $\S. 88$ (from the book) define the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ of a bounded linear operator as follows:

> $\Vert A \Vert = \inf \big\{K: \Vert Ax \Vert \leq K \Vert x \Vert \text{ for all vectors } x \big\} = \sup \left\{\frac{\vert (Ax,y) \vert}{\Vert x \Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert}: x \neq 0, y\neq 0 \right\}.$

In my attempt thus far, I have only been able to progress to the following conclusion, and would appreciate a pointer. Thanks.

---

The assertion obviously holds if $x = 0$. If $x \neq 0$, then the self-adjoint nature of $AB$ means that $$\vert(ABx, x)\vert \leq \Vert AB \Vert \cdot \Vert x \Vert^2 \leq \Vert A \Vert \cdot \Vert B \Vert \cdot \Vert x \Vert^2 .$$

Comment: What is the definition of "positive linear transformation"? Is it $(Ax ,x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in X$?

Comment: @gerw Yes. That’s the definition for a positive linear transformation, as given in the book.

Comment: @RajPanse Is there no requirement that $A$ be self-adjoint if the underlying field is real? If not, there are simple counterexamples.

Comment: @gerw My apologies -- my previous answer was not accurate. The correct definition of a positive linear transformation (from $\S 72$ of the book) is as follows. A linear transformation $A$ on an inner product space is *positive* if $A$ is self-adjoint and if $(Ax, x) \geq 0$ for all vectors $x$.

Comment: @MaoWao Your question is spot on. I have just corrected the definition of a positive linear transformation in my previous comment.